# IOS UIScrollview not allowing keyboard to close when screen touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I built an app that when a textview was filled in, the keyboard would pop up and allow you to type. If I decided that I didn't want the keyboard up, I could tap the background view controller and it would fall away.  Now, I added a scrollview. Everything works fine, but I cannot get the actions to connect and make the keyboard fall away when touching outside the textview.
(I cannot make a custom view controller in Xcode)

Does anyone have any fixes?

Thank you in advance!

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *actionField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *impactField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *resultField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(



    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]
         fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            UITextField *theField = self.lineFields [i];
            theField.text = array [i];
        }



 }
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                              object:app];
}

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:
    (NSNotification *)notification
    {
    NSString *filePath = [self
                          dataFilePath];
    NSArray *array = [self.lineFields valueForKey:@"text"];
    [array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

 }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap: (id)sender {
    [self.actionField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.impactField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.resultField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks for looking Raptor.  I didn't add the code because I thought it was a Xcode connection issue

Comment: For my knowledge touchbegan function is not working in scrollview. Better whenever user is scrolling you can close the keyboard. Otherwise add one toolbar button(close) with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapScrollView:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and for the action:

```
- (void)tapScrollView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture { 
    [self.actionField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.impactField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.resultField resignFirstResponder];
}
```